# Angular material not firing scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I am currently creating an angular app with angular material. And I have an issue with scroll event.

My app is composed of a left sidenav which is fixed, and a content on the right. I try to inspect scroll on the content on the right, but without any success. I think layout directives provoke this bug.

This is an html example of my problem :

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" layout="row" ng-cloak>

 <md-sidenav layout="column" md-is-locked-open='true'>
   SideNav
   </md-sidenav>

  <md-content flex layout="column" scroll>
    <ng-view>
      <div class="test">Content</div>
    </ng-view>
  </md-content>
</body>
```

The javascript :

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        angular.element($window).on("scroll", function() {
            if (this.pageYOffset >= 100) {
                 console.log('Scrolled below 100px');
             } else {
                 console.log('Scrolled above 100px');
             }
        });
    };
});
```

If the `<div class="test"></div>` has a huge height, `<md-content></md-content>` will be scrollable, and I could normally fire scroll event with my directive `scroll`.

So I put the height of `<div class="test"></div>` to 1500px :

```
md-sidenav  {
  width: 110px;height:100%;
  padding:20px;
  background-color: #6bc7cc;
}

md-content {
  background-color : tan;
  height:100%;
  padding:20px;
}

.test {
  height: 1500px;
}
```

Unfortunately it's not working and I can't fire scroll event. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix that ?

PS : here is a fiddle of my problem : https://jsfiddle.net/wahddee2/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your `element` that is scrolling, not `$window`, so that's what you should attach the event listener to.

```
element.on("scroll", function() {
    console.log(element[0].scrollTop);
});
```